# Passing this javascript object from jQuery to PHP?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, arrays

This question stems from [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22643879/how-to-extract-text-inside-nested-html-using-jquery).

I've followed the answer below but am having trouble with passing the object into PHP. I think it's only a minor problem but I can't find it.

My ajax call

```
 $('.actResult').click(function() {
        var result = {};
        $('.actResult tr').each(function(){
            var $tds = $(this).find('td');
            result[$tds.eq(0).html()] = $tds.eq(1).text();
        });
        console.log(result);
        $.ajax({
            type: 'get',
            url: 'userpage.php',
            data: result
        });
        $('.FindResults').dialog("close");
    });
```

In userpage.php, I'm using this:

`echo '<div id="data"><pre>', var_dump($_GET), '</pre></div>';`

Possibly I might need to use stringify or json_decode, but [this source](https://www.zulius.com/how-to/send-multidimensional-arrays-php-with-jquery-ajax/) tells me it's enough to do an ajax call.

The output is giving me an

```
array(0){
}
```

Which is strange. The array prints into the console so it's generated properly. The console also tells me the ajax is executed successfully. I'm using $_GET just because $_POST already has so many variables, it's easier to inspect $_GET for this request.

UPDATE:

From the comments below, the ajax call doesn't do anything when the query is successful. So I changed the call:

```
$.ajax({
            type: 'get',
            url: 'userpage.php',
            data: result,
            success: function(){
                $('#data').text( data );
            }
        });
```

And the PHP

`echo '<input type="text" id="data" /><pre>', var_dump($_GET), '</pre>';`

I tried it with a div instead of a textbox. The result still is array(0){}

Comment: what is not working ?

Comment: @undefined `echo` can take multiple arguments, separated by commas. It's equivalent to concatenating them in to one string and passing them as a single argument. See http://php.net/echo

Comment: I'm getting an array(0){} result. And yes, I do for echos. For string variables, I use `.`

Comment: @markovchain You are building a javascript object not an array.

Comment: Where are you seeing the output from PHP? There doesn't seem to be a response callback for that `$.ajax` call. If you use your browser's dev tools (or Firebug or similar) can you see the request URL being constructed correctly?

Comment: @mycholan ah, my mistake. Then I'll edit the post to know how to pass the object :)

Comment: @IMSoP I'm just echoing the $_GET. Right now, I'm not actually doing anything with the values, I'm just trying to see if it gets received correctly. The console gives me this "XHR finished loading: "http://..." which tells me it sent correctly, right? So I should be able to see the $_GET be populated with this?

Comment: Could you please explain what you mean by this? `I'm using $_GET just because $_POST already has so many variables`. What does that even mean?

Comment: Oh, well I was using var_dump() on $_POST, but doing so shows everything that $_POST contains, so it shows $_POST['token'], for example, and a long list of other things which make it hard to see the result only

Comment: How would $_POST['token'] exist at all if you're doing a GET?

Comment: Exactly, that's why I'm using $_GET. I defined some other fields inside a form that uses the post method so the $_POST is populated with many things already. I'll switch to a $_POST as you suggest, though

Comment: No, don't switch this to a POST, you're not POSTing anything, you're GETting the user data! Please read up on http methods and rest: http://www.restapitutorial.com/lessons/httpmethods.html

Comment: OK, thanks. It's a little confusing, with you questioning me why I used a get, and then telling me get is the right one to use.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$.ajax({ 
   type       : "GET",  
   data       : { result : JSON.stringify(result) },  
   dataType   : "html",  
   url        : "userpage.php",  
   beforeSend : function(){ },
   success    : function(data){ console.log( data ) },
   error      : function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) { }
});
```

in your php

```
echo '<div id="data"><pre>'. $_GET["result"] .'</pre></div>';
```

Comment: The dataType is html here, not json.

Comment: It doesn't print the result in the PHP like this. This time what it prints is NULL instead of an empty array. I've also tried replacing the dataType with html. It prints into the console the html code for the entire page, and it worked. It did display on the console.

Comment: @markovchain try without var_dump(), i have updated my answer.

Comment: @markovchain also you have syntax error at echo, replace the ',' with '.'

Comment: `.` works fine for me.... but this code works! I'm getting a proper json version of the result object now. Thank you!

Comment: This is a band-aid solution, does not fix the underlying issue.

Comment: @JoeFrambach what's the underlying issue?

Comment: The underlying issue is that somewhere in your server-side, you're conflating $_POST and $_GET in the same request. Only one of these should ever contain anything. You can't do a POST and a GET in the same request

Answer (score 1):

```
  $.ajax({
    type: 'GET',
    url: 'userpage.php',
    data: result,
    dataType : 'json',
    success: function(data){
     console.log(data);
   },
   error: function(jqXHR, textStatus){
    console.log(jqXHR);
     console.log(textStatus);
  }
});
```

> - look at the console log and check the problem...

ahh another thing on the *userpage* use like this:

```
echo json_encode($_GET);
```

Answer (score 0):

You know what, I'm going out on a limb here, and taking a wild guess.

I think you're lying to us.

Based on this sentence in your question: `I'm using $_GET just because $_POST already has so many variables`.

You're doing a POST, not a GET. Why would $_POST contain *anything* if you're sending a GET?

Change your ajax from this

```
    $.ajax({
        type: 'post',
        url: 'userpage.php',
        data: result
    });
```

to this

```
    $.ajax({
        type: 'get',
        url: 'userpage.php',
        data: result
    });
```

Comment: That would be a relief if that was the error, but unfortunately not

Comment: Could you please explain why $_POST has anything in it?

Comment: The page has a large form basically, where the information for the result object here comes from.

Comment: I thought userpage.php was just `echo '<div id="data"><pre>', var_dump($_GET), '</pre></div>';`. That's no large form.

Comment: No, it's not the entire userpage.php. But the other codes aren't relevant to the question so I didn't show it, such as codes for connecting to the database, etc. There's also a hidden input field where the token comes from for protection purposes. I was just trying to print into the same page the result of the ajax call.

Comment: I'm glad you didn't post the entirety because I'm sure it looks like this: http://www.anfocal.ie/wp-content/uploads/2013/02/COOKERY-CORNER-SPAGHETTI-CARBONARA.jpg

Comment: Yes and no. I'm actually using PHP classes and includes for almost everything, etc, but this particular page simply can't be broken up in that way, or rather it is more difficult to do so. It can probably be minimized, which I'll do in the future. Right now I'm just making it work.